# Get last message date visible on a Slack channel

Tags: c#, slack-api, slack

Whenever a team exceeds 10000 messages then older messages are not visible in free trial teams.How can I get the last message's date, which is visible on a channel?

For example, Today is February 15,2016. If I have access to a public channel 'ChannelDemo' and my team has exceeded 10000 messages.When i go to channel 'ChannelDemo' and it shows messages from February 14,2016.

How can I get this date Feb14,2016(the date from which messages are visible on my channel - 'ChannelDemo') programmatically or through any method/web api call?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As per Slack, it is not possible to directly get the last message detail in our application.

However they have provided method Channels.History (https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) through which message details of channel could be fetched.